# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in C:\xampp\htdocs\forgot.php

Tags: php

I need your help please, I have tried with several codes, The code is to recover password, but it does not run on xampp

I have a problem with xampp: 
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in C:\xampp\htdocs\forgot.php

Is my code

```html
<?php
 if(User == false) { 

    //Pass
        if(isset($_POST['emailAddress'])){
            $email = FilterText($_POST['emailAddress']);
            $buscar = mysql_query("SELECT mail FROM users WHERE mail = '".$email."'");
            $_SESSION['correo'] = $email;
            if(mysql_num_rows($buscar) > 0){
                $_SESSION['tmptxt_seg'] = GenerateCode();
                $code = $_SESSION['tmptxt_seg'];
                mail($email,'Recuperación de contraseña - iZabbo', "Estimado usuario, hemos detectado la solicitud del cambio de tu contraseña correctamente. Si no es as&iacute; ignora este mensaje, de lo contrario haz clic <a href='http://izabbo.com/account/password/resetIdentity/9346b03cbb86c009501ce113cb38dce39ebba9c34a6416d8edef5ac544db7dddb5158bf4e86bc09c089a3ed7e87049f144888ef2b45e1a02986bdc8858d82ad0dd460/?c=".$code."'>Aqu&iacute;</a> o copia el siguiente enlace:<br> http://izabbo.com/account/password/resetIdentity/9346b03cbb86c009501ce113cb38dce39ebba9c34a6416d8edef5ac544db7dddb5158bf4e86bc09c089a3ed7e87049f144888ef2b45e1a02986bdc8858d82ad0dd460/?c=".$code." <br> ¿No ha funcionado? ¡Manda nuevamente el formulario!", 'soporte@izabbo.com');

                    echo '<script language="javascript">alert("Te hemos enviado un Email con un enlace para cambiar tu contraseña. Recuerda comprobar también la carpeta de Spam");</script>'; 
                echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=/index.php">';
            }else{ 
                echo '<script language="javascript">alert("El Email ingresado no se encuentra. Intenta registrandote.");</script>';

            }
        }
    //End Pass

    $getid = FilterText($_GET['c']);
    $correo = $_SESSION['correo'];
    if(empty($getid)){
        echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=/index.php">';
    }elseif($getid !== $_SESSION['tmptxt_seg']){
        echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=/index.php">';
    }
        //NEWPASS 
        if(isset($_POST['newsena'])){
            $mail = $_SESSION['correo'];
            $contra = FilterText($_POST['newsena']);
            $contra2 = FilterText($_POST['newsena2']);
            $buscar = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE mail = '".$mail."'");
            $user = mysql_fetch_array($buscar);
            $newpassword = md5($contra);
            if(strlen($contra) < 6 || strlen($contra) > 32){
                echo '<script language="javascript">alert("Inserta una contraseña válida.");</script>';
                header("LOCATION: /account/password/resetIdentity/9346b03cbb86c009501ce113cb38dce39ebba9c34a6416d8edef5ac544db7dddb5158bf4e86bc09c089a3ed7e87049f144888ef2b45e1a02986bdc8858d82ad0dd460/?c=". $_SESSION['tmptxt_seg']."");
            }else{
                if($contra !== $contra2){
                echo '<script language="javascript">alert("Las contraseñas no coinciden.");</script>';
                header("LOCATION: /account/password/resetIdentity/9346b03cbb86c009501ce113cb38dce39ebba9c34a6416d8edef5ac544db7dddb5158bf4e86bc09c089a3ed7e87049f144888ef2b45e1a02986bdc8858d82ad0dd460/?c=". $_SESSION['tmptxt_seg']."");
                }else{
                    mysql_query("UPDATE users SET password = '".$newpassword."' WHERE mail = '".$mail."' LIMIT 1");
                    $_SESSION['Password'] = $newpassword;
                    echo '<script language="javascript">alert("Contraseña actualizada con éxito.");</script>';
                    echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=/index.php">';
                }
            }
        }
    //END NEWPASS

    ?>
```

Comment: Usually means you forgot a closing brace `}`.... Actually running it in an online beautifier it says you have an unexpected `)` at line 55

Comment: But in what line? @MiltoxBeyond

Comment: It was the curly brace at the end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot a curly bracket before the end of the PHP script to close `if(User == false) {`.
Add one just before the `?>` and it will work.